# Sharing CX Freeze folder over network

Tags: python, cx-freeze

I need to send some Python code as an executable to my coworkers (who don't have interpreters on their computers) over our network, so I'm working on learning cx_freeze. The gargantuan files created by pyinstaller weren't going to cut it on saving network space. With the setup.py file below, I had no issue making the build folder, and the exe runs perfectly on my computer:

```
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable

setup(name = "reandurllib" ,
      version = "0.1" ,
      description = "" ,
      executables = [Executable("LossChecker.py")])
```

I took the folder out of the build folder, named it LossChecker, and copied it onto our network. Unfortunately, when my coworkers try to use it, nothing happens. When I try to open it on the network, I get a blank command window. If I copy the folder out of the network and back to my computer, it works fine, but if a coworker does so, the program still won't open for them.

I'm guessing something about the network is the problem here. If that's the case, how best to share the folder? Would zipping and emailing it work? Is there a fix I can do on my end to prevent the issue in the first place? Thanks for the help.

Edit: In case it applies, here's the code for the underlying program:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import simpledialog
from tkinter import filedialog
import webbrowser
from tempfile import NamedTemporaryFile

top = tk.Tk()
top.title('Loss Checker')

my_filetypes = [('csv files', '.csv')]

base_html = """
<!doctype html>
<html><head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/css/jquery.dataTables.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
</head><body>%s<script type="text/javascript">$(document).ready(function(){$('table').DataTable({
    "pageLength": 50
});});</script>
</body></html>
"""

def df_html(df):
    df_html = df.to_html()
    return (base_html % df_html).encode('ascii')

def df_window(df):
    with NamedTemporaryFile(delete=False, suffix='.html') as f:
        f.write(df_html(df))
    webbrowser.open(f.name)

def loadnew():
    global newpath
    global new
    newpath=filedialog.askopenfilename(parent=top,initialdir="/",title="New Losses")
    new=pd.read_excel(newpath,sheet_name=None,usecols=['claim','paid','reserved','incurred','py','lob'])
    
def loadold():
    global oldpath
    global old
    oldpath=filedialog.askopenfilename(parent=top,initialdir="/",title="Old Losses")
    old=pd.read_excel(oldpath,sheet_name=None,usecols=['claim','paid','reserved','incurred','py','lob'])

def check(new,old,dif,kind):
    global output
    output=pd.DataFrame()
    for key in new.keys():
        tempnew=new[key]
        tempnew=tempnew[['claim','paid','reserved','incurred']].groupby(by='claim').sum().merge(tempnew[['claim','py','lob']].drop_duplicates(subset='claim', keep="first"),how='left',on='claim')
        tempold=old[key]
        tempold=tempold[['claim','paid','reserved','incurred']].groupby(by='claim').sum().merge(tempold[['claim','py','lob']].drop_duplicates(subset='claim', keep="first"),how='left',on='claim')
        comb=tempnew.merge(tempold,how='outer',on='claim',suffixes=['_new','_old'],indicator=True)
        comb['program']=key
        comb['Status']=comb['_merge'].replace({'both':'Recurring','left_only':'New','right_only':'Missing'})
        comb['difference']=comb['incurred_new']-comb['incurred_old']
        comb=comb[['program','claim','Status','difference']+comb.columns[1:-4].to_list()].fillna(0)
        comb['difference']=comb['incurred_new']-comb['incurred_old']
        if kind==True:
            output=output.append(comb[comb['difference']>dif])
        else:
            output=output.append(comb[comb['difference']<dif])
    output.drop(columns=['py_old','lob_old'],inplace=True)
    output['py_new']=output['py_new'].astype(int)
    if kind==True:
        output=output.sort_values(by='difference',ascending=False).reset_index()
    else:
        output=output.sort_values(by='difference').reset_index()
    output.rename(columns={'difference':'Incurred Development','py_new':'PY','lob_new':'LOB'},inplace=True)
    output.columns=output.columns.str.title().to_list()
    output.drop(columns=['Index'],inplace=True)
    df_window(output)
       
def save(df):
    save=filedialog.asksaveasfilename(parent=top,initialdir="/",title="Save As",filetypes=my_filetypes)
    df.to_csv(save)

w=tk.Button(top,text="Load New Losses",command=loadnew)
w.grid(row=0,column=1)

w2=tk.Button(top,text="Load Old Losses",command=loadold)
w2.grid(row=0,column=2)

w3=tk.Button(top,text='Greater than',command=lambda:check(new,old,int(e1.get()),True))
w3.grid(row=2,column=1)

w4=tk.Button(top,text='Less than',command=lambda:check(new,old,int(e1.get()),False))
w4.grid(row=2,column=2)

w5=tk.Button(top,text='Save',command=lambda:save(output))
w5.grid(row=3,column=1)

tk.Label(top, text="Incurred Development").grid(row=1)

e1 = tk.Entry(top)

e1.grid(row=1, column=1)

top.mainloop()
```

Comment: Could it be an issue with a path? Do you have any paths in your python file? Also cx_freeze and friends are hard to debug. Maybe having a try: except under your main and print the contents into a file?

Comment: How do you run setup.py? is that setup.py build? Also which version of numpy are you using?

Comment: Okay, so I have managed to build and run it on my system with no issues. I do not think it is a path problem nor do I think it's related to a network drive... the one difference a network drive has is that it is massively slower than a hard drive. Maybe it is taking too long to load? It should work on your machine. It may not work on your colleagues but maybe that's another issue? What if your colleagues copy it to their local drive, does that work?

Comment: Numpy 1.19.4. When my colleague copies the folder to her computer (which is, excepting the interpreter I have on mine, effectively identical) it doesn't run. I'm currently copying it out of the network folder and onto my desktop to see if simply transferring it into and out of the network is causing issue.

Comment: I think it's actually the libraries. It might be numpy... I had issues with it when I first ran it, I had to use numpy 1.18.0